# Prevent elements dragging out of canvas

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create [bounded force layout](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1129492) in d3.

I can drag nodes only within bounds of the containing SVG element. However, links are rendering out of SVG if I try to drag nodes out of bounds. I don't know how to prevent this.

[image]

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-voice-29n30?file=/src/Vis.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anonymous function inside the node's `attr` methods sets the `x` and `y` properties of the datum object. Therefore, you should change the links **after** you change the nodes:

```
node.attr("cx", (d) =>
    (d.x = Math.max(
      NODE_RADIUS,
      Math.min(d3ContainerWidth - NODE_RADIUS, d.x)
    ))
  )
  .attr("cy", (d) =>
    (d.y = Math.max(
      NODE_RADIUS,
      Math.min(d3ContainerHeight - NODE_RADIUS, d.y)
    ))
  );

link.attr("d", (d) => `M ${d.source.x},${d.source.y} L ${d.target.x},${d.target.y}`);
```